# Why I am stopped from asking or my questions are closed?

Tags: discussion

I continuously get stopped from asking questions/ closing my questions because some of the ‘community’ do not like the questions.  Clearly, some people have more influence than others.  What relevance has some people not liking my questions got to do with my questions being controlled / closed.  All the questions I ask relate to verses from the bible, I am not being rude, all questions have references from the bible.  All I can think is that some have issues as they can’t answer the questions as they do not read the whole bible only aspects or are weak in faith. If not, I would be grateful for an explanation.

Comment: Your response to a question ban is to insult people. Some of us might have been inclined to try to help you, but no, not after that.

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum; maybe you mistake the purpose of SE Q&A sies. *All I can think is that some have issues as they can’t answer the questions as **they do not read the whole bible only aspects or are weak in faith*** - Nice job there,(1) poisoning the well and (2) insulting pretty much everyone who comes to this site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this user is using a meta post to insult  the bulk of the participants at C.SE.

Answer (score 5):

You hit the question ban limit and the explanation can be found in the help center

https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans

The bans are automatic for new users; until the accumulate some rep by asking well received questions.

For other users, we should be upvoting question, that helps the site grow a bit and keeps people who ask pretty good questions from encountering this ban.

Comment: The link doesn't answer my ban, the ban appears to be some not liking my questions, maybe it challenges basic held beliefs.  Also it wasn't to insult people but an observation that this site is not for deep analysis to find the truth.  why an issue when the questions relate to evidence from the bible.  We can discuss something divisive -  is Jesus only son of God or God himself, yet my questions about verses of the bible appear to be more ban worthy.  that's why my observation people are having difficulty with answering my question otherwise they would be answered with a smile.

Comment: No, this site is not for that, it's for finding evidence for anything in the Bible, it's for bring to light scholarship on what other people have found evidence for in the Bible and other Christian sources of truth.

Comment: the question is related to finding evidence from the bible which can only be done by deep analysis or are you implying there is only 1 opinion - therefore most questions are off limit.

Comment: @anothertheory yes, we're trying to get down to just have one answer per question. At the very least questions need to be worded in a way that answers don't approach the question from different first principles.   (i.e. we don't accept Catholic answers to Mormon questions, etc...).  I understand that people who believe in persceptuity of scripture don't find this necessary.